# PostGIS find linestrings that are connected

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Hi i am trying to get all linestrings that are close to the nodes of other linestring

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lines p
JOIN lines ps ON( ST_Buffer(p.geom, 0.01) && ps.geom 
AND ST_Intersects(st_buffet(p.geom, 0.01), ps.geom))
```

But I also get lines that intersects.

There is function `ST_Touches()` however i can't figure out how can I add some tolerance. Maybe there is a way to make buffer over linestring nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to extract the nodes using [`st_dumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html), then you can join the line to these points. It is better to use `st_dwithin` rather than an inexact buffer.

The query would be similar to

```
SELECT * 
FROM lines p 
 JOIN 
   (SELECT *, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom 
    FROM lines ps) as pts 
  ON st_dwithin(p.geom, ps.geom, 0.1);
```

You might want to select something else than `*`, as you would get 3 geometries per row (1st line, 2 line, node of contact)

PS: regarding `st_touch`, the two lines can still touch each others between 2 vertices.

Comment: thank you, that is what i needed! i selected * just in this example. St_dwithin seems to be a lot faster, thank you for this hint.